# undefined reference error due to use of static variables

Tags: c++, static, static-members

I asked a question earlier today about singletons, and I'm having some difficulties understanding some errors I encountered. I have the following code:

#### Timing.h

```
class Timing {

public:
    static Timing *GetInstance();
private:
    Timing();
    static Timing *_singleInstance;
};
```

#### Timing.cpp

```
 #include "Timing.h"

 static Timing *Timing::GetInstance() {  //the first error
    if (!_singleInstance) {
        _singleInstance = new Timing();  //the second error
    }
    return _singleInstance;
}
```

There are two errors in this code which I can't figure out.

1. The method `GetInstance()` is declared in the header as static. Why in the cpp file do I have to omit the word `static`? It gives the error: "cannot declare member function ‘static Timing* Timing::GetInstance()’ to have static linkage". The correct way to write it is:

   ```
   Timing *Timing::GetInstance() { ... }
   ```
2. Why can't I write `_singleInstance = new Timing();`? It gives the error: "undefined reference to Timing::_singleInstance". I solved this error by defining `_singleInstance` as a global var in the cpp file.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic but i feel the need to mention this: You asked a lot of questions at Stack Overflow. Most of them are answered correctly. Is there a reason causing you not to accept any of these answers? It might be frustrating for others to answer your questions, if you do not reward them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: static means "local linkage" when used for a function declaration/definition outside a class-declaration.

Local linkage means that the particular function can only be referenced from code inside this particular file, and that doesn't make much sense with a method in a class.

2: Since your class declaration can be included multiple times, the actual storage for the static member should be defined in the cpp-file:

```
#include "Timing.h"

Timing* Timing::_singleInstance;

Timing *Timing::GetInstance() {  //the first error
    if (!_singleInstance) {
        _singleInstance = new Timing();  //the second error
    }
    return _singleInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Referencing to question 2: You need to specify the static variable at the top of your cpp-file:

```
Timing* Timing::_singleInstance = NULL;
```

Comment: yes i figured it out eventually, but i'm wondering if i already defined it in the header file, why can't i use it in the cpp file?

Comment: you declared it in the header file but didn't define it. You essentially say that this class has such a (static) member but the compiler doesn't know in which object file you want to reserve memory for it.

Comment: Like Andre pointed out, you need to allocate memory for static variables before the actual program begins to operate. Static variables are _allways_ available.

Comment: i understand now.. thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 1):

1. `static` within a class means something completely different than `static` outside of it.  Yeah, not the greatest design decision of C++, but, we have to live with it.
2. I imagine the whining comes from the linker, and it's because you have declared that variable but never defined it, making it an undefined references.  Just add in your `.cpp` file a line like:

   ```
   Timing* Timing::_singleInstance;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, you have to omit the static in the .cpp file
2. You'll have to 'reserve memory' for `_singleInstance` somewhere, e.g. by writing the following in the .cpp file:

   Timing *Timing::_singleInstance = NULL;

(outside the definition of the member functions)

Answer (score -1):

In the definition, you need to omit the static keyword. Its because that's teh syntax of C++. Nothing big.

Once you fix error number 1, error number 2 will be fixed automatically.

Comment: Error number 1 and 2 are unrelated.