# Static Variable Undefined Reference

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make sure that a module only loads exactly once but when I do it my way, the compiler spits out "Undefined reference to both my static class variables :S

```
class Text : public Parent
{
    private:
        static int Instances;
        static HMODULE Module;

    public:
        Text();
        Text(Text&& T); 
        Text(std::wstring T); 
        ~Text();

        virtual Text& operator = (Text&& T); 
};

Text::Text() : Parent() {}

Text::~Text()
{
    if (--Instances == 0)
        FreeLibrary(Module); // Only free the module when
                             // no longer in use by any instances.
}

Text::Text(Text&& T) : Parent(std::move(T)), Module(std::move(T.Module))

Text::Text(std::wstring T) : Parent(T)  // Module only loads when
                                        // this constructor is called.
{
    if (++Instances == 1)
    {
        Module = LoadLibrary(_T("Msftedit.dll"));
    }
}

Text& Text::operator = (Text&& T)
{
    Parent::operator = (std::move(T));
    std::swap(T.Module, this->Module);
    return *this;
}
```

Any ideas why it says undefined reference to BOTH variables (Instances & Module)?

Comment: Are the definition and implementation of the class in the same file or in separate files?  Where does the error message point to?

Comment: It points to the Cpp file that contains the definition for the class. The header and cpp file are separate. Gives no line numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to static variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331469/undefined-reference-to-static-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **define** your static variable in your before you can use it.

Add

```
int Text::Instancese = 0 // whatever value you need.
```

at top of your `.cpp` file.

Comment: Wow.. That worked.. Why though :S I don't understand why you'd declare a variable in the implementation file. I've never seen this before.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames This is C++:) I think any introduction on C++ has an explanation :D google it.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames You don’t *declare* it – you *define* it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the wording.

Answer (score 1):

The class definition **declares** two static data members, `Text::Instances` and `Text::Module`. You also have to **define** those data members if the code actually uses them. Just like `void f();` **declares** a function, but you can't call it unless you also **define** it. So add:

```
int Text::Instances;
HMODULE Text::Module;
```

to your source code. (This has nothing to do with whether your current code is written entirely in a header or split into header and source; if you use it you have to define it)