# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: static class method call static class member

Tags: c++

This problem has made me feel blue, and I can't work out how to fix it.

```
class A{
public:
    static int get_A() {
        return a;
    }
    static int get_B() {
        return b;
    }
    static int a;
    static int b;
};

int main() {
    int c = A::get_A(); 
    return 0;
}
```

I wanna use static an in static method get_A(), but I got compiling error as below. (please forgive me using the meanless variable name in the program like above)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "A::a", referenced from:
      A::get_A() in main.o
```

Comment: Here's a dupe more relevant to your question: [Undefined reference to static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331469/undefined-reference-to-static-variable)

Comment: 你需要在类外面定义静态变量：int A::a = 0; int A::b = 0;