# Redefining static variables to be used in Functions - Is there a better way?

Tags: c++, oop, static

I've been writing C++ (Mostly C++98) for a while and whenever I have a class using a static variable that is being accessed by a static function I must (re?)define it.

Example:

Test.h

```
class Test
{
    static bool m_Foo;

    static void Bar();
}
```

Test.cpp

```
bool Test::m_Foo; // This is what im trying to get rid of

void Test::Bar()
{
    m_Foo != m_Foo;
}
```

Now with bigger classes this becomes really messy and confusing, is there a better way to handle this? Im thinking that C11 or C17 would have a more modern way to do this. My google research only really shows solutions for functions.

Comment: What you are looking for is `inlined variable` (since c++17). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline for more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why static data members must be defined in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387460/why-static-data-members-must-be-defined-in-c)

Comment: If you have so many statics that this becomes messy and confusing, it might be time  to refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VS2017 you have to explicitly state to use **C++17 on all builds**. Rookie mistake I know ...
After switching to C++17 (Not C++14) using inline worked straight away.

The Class now looks like this:

```
class Test
{
    static inline bool m_Foo;

    static void Bar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`static bool m_Foo;` in Class Test, is a declaration
while
`bool Test::m_Foo;` is its definition, so you can't skip this.

How do I improve it?
I'm not quite sure what is the better way to handle it and look forward to see other answers.