# Why can I not push an instance of Foo into a static vector stored inside Foo?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Foo {
public:
    string name = "Guntr";
    static vector<Foo> names;
};

int main() {
    Foo myName = Foo();
    Foo::names.push_back(myName);
}
```

Why can I not push an instance of Foo into a static vector stored inside Foo?

I get the following compile error:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.2\bin
\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/untitled6.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:
(.rdata$.refptr._ZN3Foo5namesE[.refptr.
_ZN3Foo5namesE]+0x0): undefined reference to `Foo::names'
```

Is the compiler unable to determine how much memory to allocate the `vector<Foo> names` array?

Because the compiler is unhappy with this approach, would it be better to have the vector be a global or be stored in a driver class?

Comment: What is the actual problem with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Then copy-paste them (as text) into the question. Or do you get run-time errors or crashes? Do you get unexpected results? What actually happens? And what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331469/undefined-reference-to-static-variable)

Comment: Voting to reopen so that it can be closed as a dupe instead of the current reason; the edit added the necessary info.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that your static variable is undefined. Member variables have external linkage, so you have to define it somewhere outside of the class definition:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    string name = "Guntr";
    static vector<Foo> names;
};

vector<Foo> Foo::names;
```